# How does t-sql update work without a join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I think my head is muddy or something. I'm trying to figure out how a t-sql update works without a join when updating one table from another. I've always used joins in the past but came across a stored proc where someone else created one without a join. This update is being used in SQL 2008R2 and it works.

```
Update table1

SET col1 = (SELECT TOP 1 colX FROM table2 WHERE colZ = colY),

col2 = (SELECT TOP 1 colE FROM table2 WHERE colZ = colY)
```

Obviously, colY is a field in table1.  To get the same results in a select statement (not update), a join is required.  I guess I don't understand how an update works behind the scenes but it must be doing some kind of join?

Comment: "To get the same results in a select statement, a join is required" - nope, [correlated subqueries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638.aspx) work fine in `SELECT`s too

Comment: @AakashM - i've only used joins so haven't tried selects using correlated subqueries. thanks for correcting me, i'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server translates those subqueries into joins. You can look at this by getting the query plan. You can write an equivalent query with `UPDATE ... FROM ... JOIN` syntax and observe the query plan to be essentially the same.

The sample code shown is unusual, hard to understand, redundant and inflexible. I recommend against using this style.

Comment: Actually because of the TOP 1 it is somewhat more difficult to just use an ordinary join.  Unless of course the TOP 1 is redundant and it's a guaranteed 1:1 relationship.  Because the OP is pulling 2 columns from the same table I might use a CTE and a JOIN, but the theory and use of correlated subqueries is perfectly reasonable in general.

Comment: I mean "physical join", not algebraic join. SQL Server can process correlated joins just fine with the nested loops join operator. You'd have to use a cross apply in this particular query. Subqueries are always translated to joins in SQL Server (or optimized out).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same syntax in a SELECT with no join, but you need to alias the table if colY also exists in table2

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 colX FROM table2 WHERE colZ = T.colY)
, (SELECT TOP 1 colE FROM table2 WHERE colZ = T.colY)
FROM table1 AS T
```

I only ever use this sort of thing when building up an ad hoc query just for my own infomation. If it's going to be put into any sort of permanent code I'll convert it to a join as it's easier to read and more maintainable.

Comment: Actually the table alias isn't required, it's just a good idea because it helps make the query more readable.  Now on the other hand if `coly` were to exist in both the inside and outside query then you would need to include the table alias in order to reference the version in the outside query.

Comment: I stand corrected. In my defense, I almost always use aliases anyway for readability and most of the time with queries like this I'm using self joins so the alias is required

Comment: Excellent habit to get into and one I wish all of my developers had!

Answer (score 0):

No it's doing a sub query, well two in this case. Be damn painful if you have another 98 col fields.

You can do something similar for select

```
select *,
(SELECT TOP 1 colX FROM table2 WHERE colZ = colY) as col1
From table1
```

A left join would simply be more efficient

Your example unless the dbms optimises it it running the subquery(ies) for each row in table.
Got to say whoever wrote it is less than competent.

Answer (score 0):

These subqueries are what is called correlated subqueries.  If you were to write the same query as a  `SELECT` rather than an `UPDATE` it would look like this.

```
SELECT col1 = (SELECT TOP 1 table2.colX FROM table2 WHERE table2.colZ = table1.colY),
    col2 = (SELECT TOP 1 table2.colE FROM table2 WHERE table2.colZ = table1.colY)
FROM table1
```

The `JOIN` is in the fact that you are referencing a column from an outside table on the inside of the subquery.  `Table1` is referenced in the `UPDATE` command.  You can include a `FROM` clause but it isn't required for a setup like this.

Comment: Wow, thanks everyone for all the suggestions. I'm going to learn a lot on this site